# Batch create folders then relocate exisiting folders and subfolders using text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of folders (and subfolders) in the structure of...

```
Test/Student001/ABC,
Test/Student001/DEF,
Test/Student002/ABC,
Test/Student002/DEF, etc...
```

What I then need to do is relocate those folders (and their subfolders and the files within) to another location so that it is like...

```
Test/Class01/ArronAmos(Student001)/ABC
Test/Class01/ArronAmos(Student001)/DEF
Test/Class02/BrettBesty(Student002)/ABC
Test/Class02/BrettBesty(Student002)/DEF
```

I have text files with all the folders (and subfolders) original and new names (saved like so)..

```
studentdata.txt

A (studentcode), B (studentnewname), C (Class)

Student001, ArronAmos (Student001), Class01

Student002, BrettBesty (Student002), Class02
```

Is there a way to get a batch to basically go like this (using A,B and C from text file above - preferably the one txt file if possible)...

```
md 'C' ::which will skip past if folder exists

rename folder 'A' to 'B' ::only rename of root folder and leave subfolders intact

move folder 'B' to 'C' ::move new named folder (B) and all subfolders and contents to new root folder (C)
```

The creation of the new directories and subfolders (for new and future students) goes like this and works great (except if there was a way to call a 2nd text file for the subfolder creation rather than coded in that would be awesome - but no biggy I guess)...

The Creation Batch

```
 cd /d %~dp0 pause

FOR /F "delims=~" %%f in (dirlist.txt) DO md "%%f"

:: This code creates directories referenced from a .txt file: - :: FOR /F "delims=~" %%f in (dirlist.txt) DO MD "%%f"

pause

FOR /D %%x in (*) do mkdir "%%x\Individual Behaviour Plans" "%%x\Individual Learning Plans" "%%x\Student Reports" "%%x\Student Support Group Meetings"

:: This code creates a new dir within every folder in batch location: - :: FOR /D %%x in (*) do mkdir "%%x\value"

pause
```

and this is the Rename Batch that I received off one of the other techs and don't quite understand it or know to modify it to make it work..

```
*rename_users.bat** :: Script to Rename folders - prefixing from a text file

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Set Rootfolder=Test Set Names=names.txt

:: Goto Root Folder cd /d %~dp0

:: Start Line Counter Set LineCount=0

           :: For Every folder in the directory
           For /d /r %%g in (*) DO (
                           :: Increment the line counter by 1 (see the use of "!" >instead of "%" due to delayed expansion)
                           Set /a LineCount=!Linecount!+1
                           :: Call the Rename Folder sub - passing through the >variables of folder name and line counter
                           Call:RenameFolder %%g !LineCount!)
:RenameFolder :: For all of the tokens in the findstr on the names file for /f "Tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%Names%"') DO ( :: If the line counter matches the line number If %%a==%~2 ( :: Rename the Folder Move "%~1" "%~1 %%b") ) ::Return to the Primary 
Goto:EOF

Set Rootfolder= Set Names= Set linecount= Set Drive=

Endlocal
```

The trick is we can't just use the create directories (and subdirectories) batch file, as there are some folders existing in the original format that have data in them that we need sitting in the new structures subfolders... and moving them manually would be an option... if there were not 900+ student folders to do this too...

I hope makes some form of sense... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Enter into working directory
cd C:/Test

rem Process the file with original and new names
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (studentData.txt) do (

   rem Get studentNewName end eliminate spaces
   set "studentNewName=%%b"
   set "studentNewName=!studentNewName: =!"

   rem If the new folder not exist, create it
   if not exist "%%c/!studentNewName!" md "%%c/!studentNewName!"

   rem Move files from old folder 
   move "%%a/*.*" "%%c/!studentNewName!"

   rem And delete old empty folder
   rd "%%a"

)
```

Antonio

Comment: Antonio, I have tested this batch and it seems to half work... It can create the folders and the subfolders (so the %%a,%%b and %%c seem to be working) however the part that doesnt work is the line... move "%%a/*.*" "%%c/!studentNewName!" as no data moves, and then it trys to do the line... rd "%%a" however it fails purely due to the directory not being empty yet... Any thoughts?

Comment: I played around with it and I can get it to work by switching the direction of the '/' to '\' in the move and md commands...

Comment: I also just realised the move command will only move the files in a folder, is there a way to make it move the subfolders as well I assume that would be more of an xcopy function? I will have a play and see what I can work out.. Thanks for your assistance thus far!! :)

Comment: (Sorry I am only new to this so please excuse all the comments) I swapped the 'move' to 'xcopy' and it worked a treat, then I switched 'rd' for 'rd /s /q' and that works well too!!